# Какие бесплатные онлайн конференции Вы знаете?

Tags: трансляция, презентации, чат

Требование к сервису бесплатной онлайн конференции

1. Поддержка минимум 300 человек    онлайн.
2. Возможность загрузки и отображения презентаций.
3. Возможность вывода подготовленного видео или аудио материала.
4. Видеосвязь для выступающего человека (один выступает, остальные слушают и говорят в чате).

Кто знает, подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поднимал у себя бесплатный сервис онлайн конференций. Сервисом пользовались 20 человек максимум, на счет 300 не могу сказать. Пользовался СПО   openmeetings. Скачать и почитать о сервисе можно [тут](http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/). Только, как я понял, что этот сервис требует установленной `java` на локальных ПК. Есть у этой программы возможность записи, но она косячит, возможно, кодеки не может найти или ещё чего, но решение этих проблем есть в инете. В общем, это самый простой и подходящий вариант поднять вебинар (конференцию) в локальной сети. Советую эту программу, много чего пробовал, но все это фигня.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, мой ответ не верен, но бесплатные сервисы под такие параметры не существует!Какой нормальный Админ станет грузить свою сетку на 100%, причем бесплатно?

Comment: в google есть бесплатная видео конференция между 10 участниками (грузит проц ещё по более я думаю)